# Accessing environment variable in github actions

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a web application which has different environment like development, stage and prod. Each of the environment have specific URL like

1. development:- my-app-dev.com
2. stage:- my-app-stg.com
3. prod:- my-app.com

I am building a github action which requires these URLs, I created environments under settings of my github repo and added variable name as URL in all 3 environments.
Now, i want to access this URL basis of my environment selection during runner.

So far this is how i am selecting a environment

`name: Run Playwright Tests on: workflow_dispatch: inputs: environment: type: environment description: Select the environment`

Now how do i use the environment to access the variable inside it.

I tried this

`name: Run Playwright Tests
on:
workflow_dispatch:
inputs:
environment:
type: environment
description: Select the environment
jobs:
build:
runs-on: uhg-runner-m

```
steps:
  - name: get-env-var
    run: echo "Environment is:$URL"`
```

I am expecting the output to be my-app-dev.com, if i select development during workflow dispatch

Here is the image of how i set environment variable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV6XD.png)

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
      - name: Get URL env var
        run: |
          case "${{ inputs.environment }}" in
            development) URL=my-app-dev.com ;;
            stage) URL=my-app-stg.com ;;
            prod) URL=my-app.com ;;
          esac
          echo "Environment is: $URL"
          echo "URL=$URL" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

References:

- [Providing inputs - Events that trigger workflows - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#providing-inputs)
- [Setting an environment variable - Workflow commands for GitHub Actions - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

Comment: But i want URL value to be picked up from the environment variables I have set

Comment: @CapCoder No environment variable is set in the code posted by you. The URL variable set in my answer is based on `${{ inputs.environment }}` selected by you.

Comment: ![unnamed](https://github.com/Skandh15/learner-eureka/assets/29878679/6350bc80-f829-4b41-96fc-765264cf19c4)
Setting like this @ouuan

Comment: @CapCoder You said the URLs are like `my-app.com` in your question. In this case, just replace `URL=my-app.com` with `URL="$PROD_URL"` and so on.

Comment: @CapCoder I suspect you are confused with [environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables) and [deployment environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment). The `type: environment` in workflow dispatch inputs is deployment environment. You should use options instead of deployment environments if not set.

Comment: Getting empty string

Comment: @CapCoder Please try to debug it. You can echo the environment variables and `${{ inputs.environment }}` to see their values.

Answer (score 0):

Define environments in Github - Dev, staging and prod.

Define environment specific variable for all the 3 environments - **URL** (Not Prod_URL, Staging_URL but same name). This variable value will be different for your different github environments.

Set environment in your job -

environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}

Use the variable in your job -
${{ vars.**URL**}}